# How to make changes to a HTML file's fields through a Javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

Hello everyone I am on a project in which i want to change the values of html fields such as textarea checkbox etc..

I have some values on my javascript file variable,how can i assign the value of the varible to external html file's fields..

Any help should be appreciated and will be great help for me ...

```
var profiledata;
var ushurCallbackGetProfile = function (response) {

profiledata = response;


alert(profiledata);

// in the above "profiledata" i get some value like "HAI"..


};
```

I want to assign this "HAI" value to one html file's textarea..

HTML file's form is as follows..

```
enter code here <html><form id="userFormchange" method="post"><label style="margin-left:513px;">Display Name</label><input name="profileusername" type="text" placeholder="Your Nickname" id="nickname" style="margin-left: 82px;"></form></html>
```

I want to assign "HAI" value to the above input name "profileusername".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your textfield and set the `value` or `innerHTML` property:

HTML

```
<textarea class="content"></textarea>
```

JavaScript

```
var textarea = document.querySelector('.content');
var profiledata;

var ushurCallbackGetProfile = function (response) {
    profiledata = response;
    textarea.value = profiledata;
};

ushurCallbackGetProfile('some content');
```

JS Fiddle Example

**[http://jsfiddle.net/2hnwX/](http://jsfiddle.net/moogs/2hnwX/)**

Comment: THANKS THANKS A LOT BRO... U SAVED MY DAY ..  WORKING PERFECTLY... U ARE AWSOME ....

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp

ie. `document.getElementById(id).attribute=new value`

This should help. I believe this answers your question, but if not, I can try to help further.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
document.getElementById(textareaid).innerHTML = value;
```

or

```
document.getElementById(textareaid).value = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change a text in an Element then you have to use

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "New text!";
```